# Add span/html element after text node using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have this example

```js
$('span.first').append('<span class="second">2</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="first">1</span> HELLO
```

I get this output: `12 HELLO`

I need this output: `1 HELLO 2`

Comment: Please always include the relevant code in the question itself as I just did. The question should be self-contained and include all the relevant details without external links to the code

Comment: Note that @AlonEitan has done you a favour there - must people would vote close your question.  The message when saving the question is there for a reason

Answer (score 1):

Your code was putting the 2 as a child to the `span` element hence why it was displaying as 12. For the result you are after, simply append to the parent of that element instead:

```
$('span.first').parent().append('<span class="second">2</span>');
```

Comment: Working. Thank you!